# Gradient boosting for binary outcome - terminal nodes estimate (using R gbm)

Tags: r, boosting, derivative, log-loss

I have been searching for the answer for the below query quite a long time and found a few answers (see: 
[interpretation of gbm single tree prediction in pretty.gbm.tree](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/237582/interpretation-of-gbm-single-tree-prediction-in-pretty-gbm-tree)
or [R Package GBM - Bernoulli Deviance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5452/r-package-gbm-bernoulli-deviance)) that actually didn't satisfied me, therefore my post here.

What I would like to know is **why** the terminal nodes are estimated in R gbm package (when using bernoulli distribution) like in the specification below (more details: http://www.saedsayad.com/docs/gbm2.pdf):

[image]

I have read so far that in GBM:

> *the individual trees are fit to predict the gradient of the loss*
>   *function evaluated at the current prediction and the response*

where in the case of the binary outcome the current prediction are logodds, not probability (so we take the derivative of loss function with respect to logodds). Therefore, shouldn't those terminal nodes show the mean value of the **gradient** of the loss function (equation below)?

$\nabla L(y, f) = y - \frac{1}{1 + e^{-f}}$, where $f$ are logodds;

From specification in pdf ang image above it rather looks like the terminal nodes show the mean value for the derivative of loss function with respect to p, not logodds:

$\frac{\partial L}{\partial p}=\frac{y-p}{\left(1-p\right)p},$
of course if we write the loss function as

$-\sum_i[ y_i \log p_i + (1-y_i) \log(1- p_i)]$

and it can be also confirmed by the sample **R code** below:

```
    #sample data
    data <-
    data.frame(bankrupt = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  male = c(T, T, T, T, T, F, F, F, F, F))

    #simplified model
    bnk.gbm <- gbm(formula = bankrupt ~ factor(male),
           distribution = "bernoulli",
           data = data,
           n.trees = 1,
           shrinkage = 1,
           interaction.depth = 1,
           bag.fraction = 1,
           n.minobsinnode = 1)

    #terminal nodes estimates
    pretty.gbm.tree(bnk.gbm)
```

From the above we receive $-1.66667$ and $1.66667$ as terminal nodes estimates and those values can be replicated by:

```
    data$p <- 1/(1+exp(-bnk.gbm$initF))
    data$temporary <- (data$bankrupt - data$p)/(data$p*(1-data$p))
    data <- 
    data %>% group_by(male) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(terminal.node.est = mean(temporary)) %>% ungroup() %>% select(-temporary, -p)
```

I am a little bit confused why we not use the gradient as an estimation in here and what is the intuition/math behind the R gbm solution. I would appreciate any help.